# NUXT does not optimize static site

Tags: vue.js, webpack, static, nuxt.js

I have a project in NUXT js and I want to generate a static website.
It does work, but does not optimize it: does not extract the css in a single file with build.extractCSS for example.
Is it something related to the static mode?

I also try some other optimization but they don't seems to work either.
Here my config:

```
export default {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  target: process.env.NODE_TARGET === 'static' ? 'static' : 'server',
  router: {
    base: '/myRoute/',
    routeNameSplitter: '/'
  },
  server: {
    host: "localhost" // default: localhost
  },
  head: {
    titleTemplate: 'myProject',
    title: 'myProject',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      {
        hid: 'icon',
        rel: 'icon',
        type: 'image/png',
        href: '/favicon.png'
      }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
    '~/assets/css/custom.css'
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [

  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/typescript
    '@nuxt/typescript-build',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/vuetify
    ['@nuxtjs/vuetify', { treeShake: true }],
    "@nuxtjs/svg",
    'vue-social-sharing/nuxt'

  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/pwa
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
  ],
  pageTransition: {
    name: 'slide-fade',
    mode: 'out-in'
  },
  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {},
  env: {
    NUXT_ENV_API_HOST: process.env.NUXT_ENV_API_HOST,

  },
  // PWA module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/pwa
  pwa: {
    meta: {
      /* meta options */
      theme_color: "#27363B"
    },
    manifest: {
      lang: 'en'
    }
  },

  // Vuetify module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-vuetify
  vuetify: {
    optionsPath: './vuetify.options.js',
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    treeShake: true,
    // defaultAssets: false,
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  // optimizeCSS: true,
  // extractCSS: true,


  build: {
    analyze: {
      analyzerMode: 'static'
    },

    html: {
      minify: {
        collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
        decodeEntities: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        processConditionalComments: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        trimCustomFragments: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        minifyURLs: true,
        removeComments: true,
        removeEmptyElements: true
      }
    },
    optimizeCSS: true,
    extractCSS: true,
    terser: {
      parallel: true,
      cache: false,
      sourceMap: false,
      extractComments: {
        filename: 'LICENSES'
      },
      terserOptions: {
        mangle: true,
        output: {
          comments: /^\**!|@preserve|@license|@cc_on/
        }
      }
    },

    babel: {
      plugins: [
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object", { "loose": true }]
      ]
    },

    extend(config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(obj|mtl|fbx|gltf|glb|hdr|bin)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      })
    },
    transpile: [
      "three"
    ]


  },
}
```

Comment: Why would it extract to a single CSS file?

Comment: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-build/#extractcss

Comment: Your config is missing the workaround prescribed in the docs to extract to a single file. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Not really, does not change. Btw i don't really care to extract all to a single file or to serveral, but now all the css is repeated in every page.

Comment: Why did you started fiddling with the configuration? What is the actual issue you're trying to solve here?

Comment: What I want at the moment is understanding why the css can't be saved in one or more external files, as exctractCSS should do, instead of placed in the header of each generated static page, making file bigger and repeating the same thing everywhere.